# Get number of entries in bigmap

Tags: taquito, bigmap, testing, truffle

I am currently writing tests for a contract and for one of those tests, I would like to get the number of entries in a `bigmap` field of the contract's storage. I am using JavaScript with Taquito and Truffle for these tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you will be able to achieve with Taquito (at least not for now, that will change in the future) and you have to use an indexer API. I recommend [Better Call Dev API](https://api.better-call.dev/v1/docs/index.html), you can easily get the number of keys with a fetch call to `api.better-call.dev/v1/bigmap/${network}/${big_map_id}/keys` (the big map ID should be available in Taquito by calling the `toString` method on the big map abstraction object).